# How to check if thumbnail background image equals the showcase image in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I want to fade in a thumbnail when it's not yet loaded in the showcase. Otherwise I don't want the fade in, because the image is allready loaded and the fade in looks odd.

How do I check if the thumbnail image currently is loaded as background-image in the showcase?

My HTML-part:

```
<div class="showcase pink hidden-phone">
<div class="detail">
                <div class="image">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                        <!-- Carousel items -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="active item" style="background-image: url('img/520x300.gif');">1</div>
                            <div class="item" style="background-image: url('img/520x300.gif');">2</div>
                            <div class="item" style="background-image: url('img/520x300.gif');">3</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Carousel nav -->
                        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
                    </div>                
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <span class="head">Locatie</span><br />
                    Hoogstraat te Eindhoven (centrum)<br />
                    <br />
                    <span class="head">Locatie</span><br />
                    Hoogstraat te Eindhoven (centrum)<br />
                    <br />
                    <span class="head">Verkoopprijs</span><br />
                    <span class="price">&euro; 449.000 k.k.</span><br />
                    <br />
                    <a href="#" class="info btn">Meer informatie</a>
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="choice hidden-phone">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <a href="#" class="span2 border-pink" style="background-image: url('img/140x105.gif');" rel="0"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="span2 border-blue" style="background-image: url('img/140x105.gif');" rel="1"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="span2 active border-pink" style="background-image: url('img/140x105.gif');" rel="2"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="span2 border-blue" style="background-image: url('img/140x105.gif');" rel="3"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="span2 border-pink" style="background-image: url('img/140x105.gif');" rel="4"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="span2 border-blue" style="background-image: url('img/140x105.gif');" rel="5"></a>                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Jquery-part:

```
if($('div.showcase .row-fluid').length)
{
    $('div.showcase .row-fluid').on('click','a',function(i,obj){
        var itemId =   $(this).attr('rel');
        var data   =   showcaseData[itemId];

        var htmlImg =   '';
        $.each(data.imagedirectory, function(i,obj2) {
            firstClass  =   (i == 0) ? ' active':'';
            htmlImg += '<div class="item'+firstClass+'" style="background-image: url(img/'+obj2.imgFile+');"></div>';
        });

        if (...){
            $("div.showcase div.carousel-inner").html(htmlImg);
            console.log(itemId);    
        } else {
            $('div.showcase div.carousel-inner').fadeTo(100, 0.2, function() 
            {
                $(this).html(htmlImg)
            }).fadeTo(300, 1);
            console.log(htmlImg);
        }

        $('span.location').html(data.street+' '+data.housenumber+' te '+data.city);
        $('span.metrage').html(data.metrage);
        $('span.price').html('&euro; '+number_format(data.price,2,',','.'));
        $('div.showcase a.info').attr('href',data.detail_url);
    });
}

if($('div.catalogDetail .row-fluid .thumbImages').length)
{
    $('div.catalogDetail .row-fluid .thumbImages').on('click','a',function(i,obj){
        var newImage =   $(this).attr('rel');
        $('.catalogDetail .mainImage').css('background-image','url('+newImage+')');
    });
}
```

...

Thank you!
Teun

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean seeing what background image is actually set in the thumbnail or whether an image resource has finished loading?
First option: You should be able to access the background-image property of an element with

`$('element').css('background-image');`

So you can always compare the output of that with the image URL you want to check has been loaded.
Second option: use something like

```
$('img.class').load(function() { do_things_when_loaded(); });
```

That will trigger when an image resource has actually been loaded. Hope that helps a bit!

Comment: Hey Baron, Thats not exactly what a want. I want the following:if thumbnail is loaded in .item .active then add htmlImg but without the fadeIn effect (the 'else' option).